# zero diagonal of product of skew-symmetric and symmetric matrix with strictly positive identical diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

I encountered the following problem in a proof which I couldn't solve so far:

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a skew-symmetric matrix, and $\mathbf{B}$ a symmetric matrix. There is at least one off-diagonal element in $\mathbf{B}$ which is non-zero, i.e. $\exists i,j,i \neq j: B_{ij} \neq 0$.

I now look at the diagonal elements of the product of the two matrices, $(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ii}$. I need to show: If all diagonal elements are zero, i.e. $\forall i: (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ii} = 0$, then $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}$.

Alternatively one could also show the negation: If $\mathbf{A} \neq \mathbf{0}$ then $\exists i: (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})_{ii} \neq 0$.

Any ideas?

Edit: $\mathbf{B}$ also has strictly positive and identical diagonal entries. I didn't think this condition was required, but apparently it is (as the counter-example in the answer shows).

2nd edit: That additional prerequisite doesn't change the counter-example below. I think what I wanted to show doesn't hold.

3rd edit: I probably asked the wrong question for my problem. I tried it again in a different question: [product of skew-symmetric and symmetic matrix: diagonal elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3662881/702757).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to show isn't true. Counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&-1&-1\\ 1&0&-1\\ 1&1&0},\ B=\pmatrix{0&1&-1\\ 1&0&1\\ -1&1&0},\ AB=A.
$$

Comment: Yes, you're right, thank you. That made it obvious to me that I omitted another condition, I'm sorry: $\mathbf{B}$ has identical and strictly positive diagonal elements. I didn't think that condition was required, but it seems it is. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I added a second edit: I think the diagonal elements are not of interest. So your counter-example is probably the solution: my conjecture doesn't hold.

Comment: I new refer to my new attempt in the question.